# Manage lots of tabs on Chrome

Tags: chrome

Is there any Chrome extension which can manage lots of tab - to counter too many tabs in Chrome?

I often open a lot of tabs and during work I forget to close them.

So I am looking for an extension to manage my (many) open tabs in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TooManyTabs for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp/related?hl=en):

- shows you all the tabs with a preview
- can suspend tabs to save memory
- backup open tabs to Google Drive (optional)
- 'you are here' for open tab
- search open tabs
- set shortcut to open TooManyTabs
- customizable background color
- recently closed tabs shown as well (optional)

TooManyTabs:

[image]

Settings page:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall?hl=en)

It saves all the opened links into a tab there by reducing all the tabs in one with a single [click on the extension](http://techiegenie.blogspot.in/2014/01/improve-web-browsing-experience-with.html). You also have the option to share the page containing all the links to facebook or email them .

Very simple interface.

Doesn't consume lot of RAM.

Your chrome browsing experience also increases because of less RAM consumption.